# How to get the last UIViewController visited?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that I'm using as a information page. How would I go about getting back to the last `UIViewController` visited from the information page?

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender 
{
    TennisMatch4ViewController *switcher = [[TennisMatch4ViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    switcher.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
    [self presentModalViewController:switcher animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What is UIController? I guess you mean UIViewController. How do you "get to it"? Is it a modal view controller? You really need to describe our question better and maybe give some code.

Comment: How are you displaying the vie controller. Is it modal? Is it in a navigation controller? Gonna need more information than that.

Comment: Sorry...UIViewController. I have four Modal view controllers. I'm using one for information. I want to be able to go to the information UIViewController and then go back to the last visited UIViewController .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is call:

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This will remove the current view and go back to the one before the current.